# Select options not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a dynamically generated select with some options and it shows the options fine in normal browsers, but its empty options in IE. Here's the generated HTML:

```
<select name="0" id="custom_0" style="border-bottom: #c0cedb 1px solid; border-left: #c0cedb 1px solid; background-color: #ededed; width: 280px; font-size: 0.87em; border-top: #c0cedb 1px solid; border-right: #c0cedb 1px solid">
    <option id="1000" value="0" name="00">1x2GB ECC DDRIII 2GB ECC DDRIII</option>
    <option id="1001" value="10" name="01">2x2GB ECC DDRIII 4GB ECC DDRIII (+10.00 €)</option>
</select>
```

I can't really show you the javascript, since there's so much of it and I would be able to make it simple just for a demo. Maybe you had some of you would've had a similar experience and could figure this one out. Thanks

I've added some javascript:

```
$('#custom_order').append('<tr id="custom_'+category+'_row"><td'+padding+'>'+header+'<select id="custom_'+category+'" name="'+category+'" style="background-color:#EDEDED;border:1px solid #C0CEDB;width:280px;font-size:0.87em"></select>'+plusspan+'</td></tr>');

for (var i=0;i<components[category]['value'].length;i++){
    $('#custom_'+category).append('<option id="'+components[category]['value'][i]['id']+'" value="'+components[category]['value'][i]['price']+'"></option>');
    removals(category,i);
    dependencies(category,i);
    selectInput(category);
}
getDiff(category);
```

getDiff() function adds the values to the options with html() function. The weird thing is, if I alert the html of the option just after the getDiff() function, it shows the value filled out. And it I put the getDiff() function in the for loop where the options are generated, it fills the values and shows them in IE, just not the last one.

I'm calling getDiff() outside the loop for optimization, and since I can add the values later after all the options are generated. Well at least I thought I could, since it works on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Can't really see any mistakes from that code, think you're gonna have to post some more code to get any help on that one. On a sidenote you should really consider skipping all the inline CSS, it's so messy.

Comment: Oh and just noticed you're using the name attribute for optiontags which shouldn't be there. Hope you don't mind the little pointers:)

Comment: Also, I notice the use of the 'Euro' monetary symbol. Try &euro; instead

Comment: I've removed the option tags but that didn't help.

Comment: I'm actually inserting &#8364; and not €

Comment: I've tried setting the values to some constant string, to see it there was a problem with that, but it didn't help.

Comment: @donkapone didn't mean you should remove the optiontags, just the name attribute which doesn't really do anything for you those tags. You need a name on the select, not on each option. But my pointers was not intended to answer your problem, only some tips to improve your code:)

Comment: I checked with the code in IE 7 and Firefox 3.5.1 , its working fine ![alt text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9h0cN.png)

Comment: Talking of name attributes, the `name="0"` in the select tag is a very poor choice of name. Numeric names and IDs are not good because they can be ambiguous, which can cause errors. Something like `name="catgegory_0"` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your JavaScript it's hard to answer this. Can you even give a sample bit of code that demonstrates how the JavaScript is doing the dynamic generation.

That said, I have encountered issues in this area before now. Generally, it has arisen from specifying the 'options' as the HTML to the select, rather than actuall creating a 'SELECT' DOM element, creating the associated 'OPTIONS' DOM elements and then correctly appending this to the DOM in the correct way.

jQuery ought to hangle this for you, but, again, its difficult to know what your issue is without at least some code.

Comment: I second these unclear/random select/option issues in IE. Try using `$('#custom_'+category).append($('<option id...`, which should create an actual DOM element instead of using innerHTML, if I'm not mistaken. Also, could you clearify if "empty options" means that the select is totally empty, or that the select has options, but their labels are empty? If the latter, just try setting the option's content (label) at creation time.

Comment: just the labels are empty. And to set the option's content at creation time would include a major change in the architecture, and I'm trying to avoid that. Maybe there's some workaround this? Since the generated HTML is correct.

Comment: we had a similar issuer where were setting options dynamically. the object in the dom were fine, but the options displayed by the browser were never refreshed. $('#mySelect').hide().show() helped for us.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem where creating options in your select doesn't show in IE.

I couldn't figure out what was going wrong as my code worked fine in FF, so I added FireBug Lite to my page, and tried inspecting the drop down list.

I could see that the options where actaully being created against the drop down list, but that IE was just not displaying them.

This appears to be a rendering issue effecting IE 7 (I havn't tested in any other versions).

What gave it away is that when you inspect your page, FireBug will apply a highlight effect on the control in focus, this highlight actually caused the drop down list to display the missing options.

So I figured that applying a style change to the drop down list should be enough to fix the problem.

```
$('<option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option>')
.appendTo($('#MyDDL'));
$('#MyDDL').css('display', 'inline');
```

You should now be able to see your options.

Comment: I had the same problem, but didn't need CSS.  I was using $('#MyDLL').append(new Option('One',1));  Dropping new Option and using your syntax worked much better.

Comment: worked for me! thanks.  I actually solved an other issue with select tag using same technique (wouldn't drop down).  I set the width wider by one pixel and then immediately set it back.

Comment: $('#MyDDL').hide().show(); will force IE to re-render the select list and show the new options

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem.  I was using IE 8. I was using a $.each statement to fill my dropdownlist as follows:

```
$.each(myObject.categories, function (count, item) { $('#ddlCategories').append(new Option(item, count)); });
```

This worked fine in chrome and FF, but not IE.  I switched to:

```
$.each(myObject.categories, function (count, item) { $('#ddlCategories').append('<option value="' + count + '">' + item + '</option>'); });
```

and it worked fine in all 3 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem when I was using innerHTML to insert options generated as text strings. The solution was to do the job properly by appending the options to your select e.g.

```
var optionRow = document.createElement("option");
optionRow.setAttribute("value", varName1);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(varName2);
optionRow.appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById("id_of_select").appendChild(optionRow);
```

IE was happy then. (So was I.)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this behavior because **id** and **name** attributes are not expected in **option** tags by some browsers.

Comment: I don't have the name attribute as of now, but I very much doubt that the id attribute is not expected. Any element can have an id attribute, is that not right?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. After much messing about, following the suggestions given by other respondents I found that the only way to get things to work in IE8 was to build the complete option string and then store it with $(#idOfMyElement).html(some data)

```
> <select id='mySelect'>
>     <option>Dummy placeholder</option>  
   </select>
> 
> <script type='text/javascript'>
> 
>     $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});    // Or next time IE will not run your script
> 
>     function setOption(...) {
>        ...
>        data = ' ... ';
>        $('#mySelect').html(data);
>        ...
>     }  </script>
```