# Selectlist text displays old values after changing with jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got 2 dropdowns, is for categories and one is for subcategories. When the category dropdown is changed the subcategory dropdown gets updated with jQuery/ajax to display new subcategories. It works great in Chrome but IE does not display the new values after being updated through jQuery. The odd thing is after selecting a new option the correct text shows up but when I have the list pulled down it displays the old text.

This is how I'm emptying and refilling the subcategory dropdown when the category changes:

```
   $('#testselectsubcat').empty().append(new Option("Pick a subcategory", 0));

   $.each(subcategories, function (index, subcat) {
       $('#testselectsubcat').append(new Option(subcat.name, subcat.id));
   });
```

Edit: forgot this part, might be important. The issue only happens with dropdowns added using jQuery after the page is loaded. I add the category dropdown to the page using .append() and the subcategory dropdown using .after().

How do I get it to work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

well, you have to clear the subcategories drop down, like this

```
// C#:
subcategories.Items.Clear();
// and loaded with new data
 ....

// or clear or empty it using jQuery
 $('#subcategories').chilren().remove();
  $('#subcategories').empty();
```

Comment: I do empty the subcategories, see the first line of code above. Does it require .children().remove(); as well?

Comment: Well, you need to clear it in server side
subcategories.Items.Clear();

Comment: But it's all client side. I don't hit the server or refresh the page when I change the options.

Comment: You now ask your self why I need to clear it in server side when I already cleared it in client side  ?
well, asp.net store the values of the form controls in a _hidden filed name _VIEWSTATE , and serialize the form and values. So you need to clear it in server side.

Comment: Using C# MVC, no viewstate.

Comment: Is the drop down list doesn't get empty in IE without load new values? , or the values return with old values, you need to debug both Javascript side  and asp.net side.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [IE doesn't work using the append method with `new Option()`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1641)

You could try to append `$('<option/>').text(x).val(y)` like:

```
$('#testselectsubcat').empty().append(
    $('<option/>').val(0).text("Pick a subcategory")
);

$.each(subcategories, function (index, subcat) {
    $('<option/>').val(subcat.id).text(subcat.name).appendTo('#testselectsubcat');
});
```

or [see here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/) for other ways using `new Option()` to work around IE

Comment: Interesting bug. I had $('<option/>') and changed to Option() in trying to fix it. Same results unfortunately.

Comment: hmmm.. What version of IE are you using? What Jquery Version? Try this jsfiddle, works fine for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/webchemist/tkBcy/

Comment: IE 9 and jQuery 1.5.2. Stuck with an old version on the site for now. Oh, and this might be important, should put it in the question, the issue only happens with dropdowns I create after the pages loads with jQuery.

Comment: in your $.each() loop are you able to put an alert(subcat.name) and see the name? I'm not sure the issue would be with the select being created after load, if the change event weren't bound then I don't think it would work in Chrome either, and you'd see no change instead of temporarily showing the new value before pulling open... If you can make a jsfiddle or post a link a page showing the issue I'd be glad to take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcthink/Cn5UF/ is a sample that has the problem in IE. Choose category 1, then category 2 then choose a subcategory. The text in the dropdown is the subcategories from category 1 but the values are from the subcatory 2 list

Comment: it appears to be an IE rendering bug, when I add subsel.hide().show(); the list now displays correct since it forces the element to rerender: http://jsfiddle.net/Cn5UF/9/ - let me know if you run into any more issues

Comment: related, see mindless' answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624120/select-options-not-showing-in-ie