# Select box options not visible in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am using Javascript to create a `<select>` box. It is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer the `<option>`s are not visible.

**HTML**

```
<select id="categroy_renew" name="categroy_renew" onchange="category_check()" style="width:310px; height:35px; padding:8px; margin-left:95px;">
    <option value="0">Select Your Category</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var category_vals = document.getElementById("categroy_renew");
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        category_vals.appendChild(new Option("PK-"+data[i].cat,data[i].cat));
    }
}
```

I tried `category_vals.innerHTML` - it not even displayed the default `<option>` "Select your category", although it is present in HTML.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Please check this Thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624120/select-options-not-showing-in-ie

Comment: Actually i am new to it, Its working fine in Firefox and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add() function of javascript

```
var category_vals = document.getElementById("categroy_renew");

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "PK-"+data[i].cat,data[i].cat;
    category_vals.add(option);
}
```

Comment: [Interface HTMLSelectElement *add* method.](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-14493106)

Comment: Thanks, It worked :-) But how i can remove "PK-". I mean to say actually i want to display pk - 1, 2 and so on but as a value i want to pass only integer value.